# why in this isset and !empty if block else statement executing by default?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) )
{
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'Enter Password';
}
?>
<form action="md.php" method="POST">
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The problem is that when I run this code then by default I see the message `Enter Password` displayed above the password field somehow the else condition is getting executed when I open this page on xampp server that `else` block is supposed to execute when the user submits empty form and not when I open the page on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The first time you run this form, from entering the url in a browser address bar of clicking on a link or menu item on another page, the `$_POST` array will be empty.

So your code will cause the `else` to be run and `echo 'Enter Password';` will be executed

When you press the Submit button, assuming you enter a password, then the $_POST will exist and `$_POST['pass']` will contain a value and you should see the `ok` message. If you do not enter anything in the `pass` password field you will of course see the `echo 'Enter Password';` again

If you only want to see the message when you have forgotten to enter  password, but pressed the Submot button, which is what I assume you are saying then try this change

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ) {
    // only set when the form was actually posted
    // not set when you run form from a link or the address bar

    if( !empty($_POST['pass']) ) {
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        // pressed submit without entering a password
        echo 'Enter Password';
    }

}
?>
<form action="md.php" method="POST">
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `else` to:

```
} else if (isset($_POST["pass"]) && empty($_POST["pass"])) {
```

You code should have 3 paths:

- There is a password and it's not empty (show ok + form)
- There is a password and it's empty (show entry pw + form)
- There is no password (show form)

Right now you only have 2 paths.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the page is opened, it gives you the `else` block because the `if statement` is false. So edit the `else-if statement` as describe below, Furthermore, leave the `action = ""` So it doesn't direct you to another page when you press the `submit` button. Try this:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) )
{
       $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    echo 'ok';
} else if( isset($_POST['pass']) && empty($_POST['pass']) ) {
    echo 'Enter Password';
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The above code should display the form, the very first time you open it and accordingly as you input/leave the `password` field afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your PHP code to:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit'])
{
    if( isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) )
    {
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'Enter Password';
    }
}
?>
```

This way the code will only run once you click the Submit button and not when you load the page.